# Using a APC Smart-UPS to shutdown a Ubuntu Server Cluster

Tags: linux, ubuntu, shutdown

I'm currently in the process of designing a solution to shutdown a two Ubuntu Server cluster that uses heartbeat and DRBD to replicate storage and offer a NFS share to some IP cameras.

We want to integrate a UPS into the system so the servers will shutdown gracefully. I'm currently looking into the APC Smart-UPS C 1000VA 2U LCD 120V UPS  and using Apcupsd to shutdown the servers in the event of a power outage.

Is this idea possible? I'm reading through the documentation right now. If you guys have any better ideas I'm open for suggestions.

Comment: It looks like that UPS would only connect to one of the servers through a USB cable. I need to communicate with both servers in case one goes down.

Comment: I found this interface card. It looks like it would allow me to connect to two servers. http://www.apc.com/products/resource/include/techspec_index.cfm?base_sku=AP9607&tab=documentation

Answer (score 4):

You could use [Network UPS Tools](http://www.networkupstools.org/) aka `NUT` instead of `apcupsd` to gracefully shut down a cluster of machines.  One machine would be the 'master' connected to the UPS serial/USB/SNMP/whatever port, the rest 'slaves' connected to the master.  If power fails, the master tells the slaves to shut down.

Comment: I thought about this, but with the environment these servers are in I can't do something like that. What if master suffers a hardware failure? The secondary will end up getting shut down incorrectly and will lead to more problems.